# Expected behaviour of a Repository

Tags: orm, domain-driven-design, unit-of-work, ddd-repositories, poeaa

I'm writing an ORM and am unsure of the expected behaviour of the Repository, or more precisely, the frontier between the Repository and the Unit Of Work.
From my understanding, a Repository might look like this:

```
interface IPersonRepository
{
    public function find(Criteria criteria);
    public function add(Person person);
    public function delete(Person person);
}
```

According to Fowler (*PoEAA*, page 322):

> A Repository mediates between the domain and data mapping layers, acting like an in-memory domain object collection. [...] Objects can be added to and removed from the Repository, as they can from a simple collection of objects.

This would imply that the following test should work (assuming that we already have a Person persisted, whose last name is Fowler):

```
collection = repository.find(lastnameEqualsFowlerCriteria);
person = collection[0];

assertEquals(person.lastname, "Fowler");

person.lastname = "Evans";
newCollection = repository.find(lastnameEqualsFowlerCriteria);

assertFalse(newCollection.contains(person));
```

That means that when mapping to a database, even if no explicit save() method has been called somewhere, the Person model must have been automatically persisted by the Repository, so that the next query returned the correct collection, **not** containing the original Person.

But, isn't that the role of the Unit Of Work, to decide which model to persist to the database, and when?

In the above implementation, the Repository has to decide to persist the Person previously retrieved when receiving another find() call, so that the result is consistent with the modification. But if no other find() call were issued, the model would not have been persisted implicitly at all.

In the context of a Unit Of Work, it is not really a problem, because we can start a transaction at the beginning, and rollback any insert to the db anyway if needed.
But when used alone, can't this Repository lead to unexpected, unpredictable behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A Repository mediates between the
>   domain and data mapping layers, acting
>   like an in-memory domain object
>   collection. [...] Objects can be added
>   to and removed from the Repository, as
>   they can from a simple collection of
>   objects.

This does not mean you do not need a save method. You still need to explicitly commit your changes to storage.

See [The Unit Of Work Pattern And Persistence Ignorance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx)

```
public interface IUnitOfWork {
  void MarkDirty(object entity);
  void MarkNew(object entity);
  void MarkDeleted(object entity);
  void Commit();
  void Rollback();
}
```

In a way, you can think of the Unit of Work as a place to dump all transaction-handling code. The responsibilities of the Unit of Work are to:

- Manage transactions.
- Order the database inserts, deletes, and updates.
- Prevent duplicate updates. Inside a single usage of a Unit of Work object, different parts of the code may mark the same Invoice object as changed, but the Unit of Work class will only issue a single UPDATE command to the databas

Comment: Thank you Todd, but my question was focused on the Repository pattern for now. Do you mean that I should add a `save(Person person)` function to the Repository? But what if for tests, I use a Memory strategy for my Repository, and for production a Database strategy; I will get different results from both, because the Memory stategy will return a different collection to the second find() call, even if the Person has not been save()d?

Comment: I would write tests that focus on simple CRUD operations doing a single read/update/validate. You normally don't want to run a series of tests using the same instance of your memory based repository. I always create a new memory repository for each test method that gets run.

Comment: Got you, makes a bit more sense like that. I still think that a Repository that 100% matches PoEAA's description is something really tricky, if not impossible in the real world! Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Update: I just found out that ORMs like Hibernate do solve this problem by flushing the changes to the database automatically when a `find()` call is issued, to guarantee consistent reads. This still has to be performed in the context of a Unit Of Work however, or the changes could not be rolled back if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you;re asking about is following: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html

Repository should keep fetched objects in memory and all subsequent calls for that entity should not be retrieved from persistence storage, hence your example should work fine.

Comment: Actually, the Identity Map serves another purpose, which is to ensure that two requests pointing to the same object actually return the same instance of this object; but in my example, the find() function is expected to perform the search in the database, which is another story. If we want the second find() to return an up-to-date result, we have to flush() pending changes to the database first.